# jquery impromptu how to apply custom style on buttons

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I am using jquery impromptu for my modal confirmation boxes. I am trying to get my prompt buttons to implement a css custom style so as to hide an ugly button focus in ie compatibility mode.

How can I modify the $prompt code below to apply the style below?

css style...

```
.hideFocus {
  /* get rid of internet explorer ugly focus in ie compatibility mode */    
  hide-focus: expression(this.hideFocus=true);  /* for ie 5+ */ 
  outline: none;  /* for firefox 1.5 + */
}
```

jquery impromptu code...

```
var buttons = { };
buttons[recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirmYesOption] = true;
buttons[recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirmNoOption] = false;

$.prompt(recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm, {
    title: recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirmHeader,
    buttons: buttons,
    persistent: false,      
    submit: function(e,v,m,f){
        if (v){
            $("#hiddenRecallFourWeeksOrMore").val("true");  
            form.submit();  
        }                                       
    }
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$.prompt(recallOfFourWeeksOrMoreConfirm, {
    buttons: {"mybuttton": true}
    classes: {button: "myclass"}
    .....
}
```

and then add styles to that class `myclass`